# Visualize Outputs of each Layer or the whole Graph from ```tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()```

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have fond some neural network online, that I want to examine a little further.
However, I only have access to the TensorFlow computation graph itself. This is loaded from  a ".pb" file.

I know how to extract the name of each operation in the graph running through the nodes of `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node` and then extracting the name with `.name`.

Is there any possibility that I can get the output shape of each layer?